# Addressing a certain element in a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I started programming a bit with HTML/CSS/js and I have a table with several rows with 2 elements each I was wondering how it's possible to give certain td Elements a text through a JavaScript function without giving them all an unique id or something.

I am searching for something similar to

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  table.at[i] = i+3;
}
```

and I am missing the `at[i]` part for it.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector()` with an [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `children` attribute

If you want to access the `n`th row of a table, use `table.children[n+1]` (first child of table is the header, if you don't have a header remove the +1). If you want to get to row `y` and column `x`, `table.children[y+1]. children [x]`.